# oracle select query with where clause returns incomplete record when run using php script

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I have an sql query that runs just fine when directly run in Oracle SQL developer which shows 3k+ records. The problems comes when I run it through a php script it only shows about 20+ records please help! btw both queries are used the same values for WHERE clause i also tried using order by but same results appear.

here my query:

sql run in php:

```
function getAllCOBDataList() 
{
            $branchcode = $_SESSION['branchcode'];
            $officeId = $_SESSION['officeid'];
            //$expenseFilter = $_SESSION['earmark-expenseCode'];
            $cob_data_list = array();

            $conn = persistentDBConnect();

            $query = "WITH CTE_TotalBalance AS (Select BUDGETID ,sum(TOTALCOST)"
                   . " as CURRENT_BALANCE from (Select BUDGETID, TOTALCOST from"
                   . " FARU.BEMM_DATA_COB"
                   . " Union all"
                   . " Select BUDGETID, EARMARKAMOUNT "
                   . " from FARU.BEMM_TRANS_EARMARKINGLIST)"
                   . " GROUP BY BUDGETID)"
                   . "SELECT"
                   . " A.FYEAR, A.BUDGETID, A.PERSPECTIVEID as perspective, A.FUNDTYPE, A.PARTICULAR, A.TOTALCOST,"
                   . " A.Q1UNITS, A.Q2UNITS, A.Q3UNITS, A.Q4UNITS,"
                   . " B.PERSPECTIVEID, B.PERSPECTIVEDESC,"
                   . " C.BPAID, C.BPADESC,"
                   . " D.INITIATIVEID, D.INITIATIVEDESC,"
                   . " E.STOBID, E.STOBDESC,"
                   . " F.TARGETID, F.TARGETDESC,"
                   . " G.OFFICEID, G.BRANCHCODE, G.PPACODE, G.PPADESC,"
                   . " H.SUBOFFICEID, H.SUBPPADESC,"
                   . " I.EXPCODE, I.EXPCODEDESC,"
                   . " J.EXPENSECLASS, J.EXPENSEDESC,"
                   . " K.CURRENT_BALANCE"
                   . " FROM"
                   . " FARU.BEMM_DATA_COB A"
                   . " INNER JOIN FARU.BEMM_LIB_PERSPECTIVE B ON A.PERSPECTIVEID = B.PERSPECTIVEID"
                   . " INNER JOIN FARU.BEMM_LIB_BPAS C ON A.BPAID = C.BPAID"
                   . " INNER JOIN FARU.BEMM_LIB_INITIATIVE D ON A.INITIATIVEID = D.INITIATIVEID"
                   . " INNER JOIN FARU.BEMM_LIB_STOB E ON A.STOBID = E.STOBID"
                   . " INNER JOIN FARU.BEMM_LIB_TARGET F ON A.TARGETID = F.TARGETID"
                   . " INNER JOIN FARU.BEMM_LIB_PPALIST G ON A.OFFICEID = G.OFFICEID"
                   . " INNER JOIN FARU.BEMM_LIB_SUBPPALIST H ON A.SUBOFFICEID = H.SUBOFFICEID"
                   . " INNER JOIN FARU.BEMM_LIB_EXPCODE I ON A.EXPENSECODE = I.EXPCODE"
                   . " INNER JOIN FARU.BEMM_LIB_EXPENSELIST J ON A.EXPENSECLASS = J.EXPENSECLASS"
                   . " INNER JOIN FARU.CTE_TotalBalance K ON A.BUDGETID = K.BUDGETID"
                   . " WHERE G.BRANCHCODE = '$branchcode'";
                  // . " WHERE G.OFFICEID = '$officeId'"
                   //. " Order by A.BUDGETID Asc";
            //echo $query;
            $stmt = oci_parse($conn, $query);
            $result =oci_execute($stmt);

            while($result = oci_fetch_assoc($stmt)){
                $cob_data_list[] = $result;
            }
            return $cob_data_list;


}
```

TIA!

Comment: This is just the query itself, but you are not showing the code which actually uses this string. Are you using `mysqli`, `PDO`, or what? Please edit the snippet to include the way you are actually trying to execute the query.

Comment: You are missing a quotation mark (`"`) before `WITH`

Comment: matteo.rebeschi i edited my snippet this function is called in a table from another php file.

Comment: so are you wondering why PHP is unable to display 30k+ records?  have you checked the memory footprint on the browser?

Comment: @THBBFT yes im wondering whats with it. not yet havent done  that

Comment: I suspect that the 30K records are blowing the memory limit of the browser, open single instance of the browser and a memory monitor (_task manager_ on windows) and watch the usage

Comment: @THBBFT I think not. Because I tested another page fetching 60k+ records and it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you are actually connecting to the same user & DB in PHP and in SQL Developer (a common mistake).

Try adding some `var_dump()` calls and run the query in the command line PHP to check it works.

Add some error handling, see page 161 of Oracle's free book [The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html).

You almost certainly should be using a bind variable instead of `" WHERE G.BRANCHCODE = '$branchcode'";` because this is a potential, big security hole.  And will impact application performance and scalability. Read up on [`oci_bind_by_name()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php).

When fetching lots of rows, you can tune performance with [`oci_set_prefetch()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.oci-set-prefetch.php).